# cannot find symbol: .getRuntime()

Tags: java, cmd, command, prompt

The problem that I am facing when I compile the program is that java doesn't recognize the ".getRuntime()" method. 
Here is my code below:

```
   import java.lang.*;
    public class Temp
   {
       public static void main(String [] args)
      {
         Process p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe").start(); 
         p = new Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd");
      } // main method
   } // Temp class
```

Here is the Error message:

```
    Temp.java:7: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : class getRuntime
    location: class java.lang.Runtime
       p = new Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd");
                      ^
```

1 error

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a `new` Runtime. Simplify remove the `new`.

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...");
```

Runtime has a private constructor. But it has a `static` single instance access method called [`getRuntime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#getRuntime%28%29). (It is a singleton)

Answer (score 0):

> YOu can't create object of Runtime class because it has a private constructor. It is called the singleton design design pattern.

But, a singleton class should have a static method to create only one instance of that class, in case of **Runtime class**, the method is

```
public static Runtime getRuntime();
```

So, by removing the new keyword, you can't get further error...