# Java Can't Find getRuntime() in Kmax

Tags: java

I'm on Windows and I'm trying to run an external batch file from Kmax 10.0 when I halt the data acquisition. But the java compiler does not recognize the getRuntime() method. This is the code in the HALT method in Kmax:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
```

...

```
public void HALT(KmaxToolsheet toolsheet) {

    dev.writeInt(drvslot, 1, 24, null, 0, 0);       //Disable LAM
    startStop.setProperty("LABEL", "Start DAQ");
    update_hist(null);
    tlsh.setProperty("STATUSSTR", "Hello HALT event!");

    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start run.bat");
}   //HALT
```

The java compiler gives me the error:

```
Runtime.java:220: error: cannot find symbol
compiler msg> Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start run.bat");
compiler msg>                       ^
compiler msg> symbol: method getRuntime()
compiler msg> location: class Runtime
```

I have looked all over for answers to this question. The closest I have been able to find is:

[cannot find symbol: .getRuntime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489305/cannot-find-symbol-getruntime)

but I'm not using 'new' in this case. Any ideas about what's going on would be helpful.